# ERROR pops out when {knitr} embed image in {DT} and output as pdf, please advise

Tags: r, knitr

With {knitr} & {DT}, we can embed image to DT and make a table with image and data altogether, but it generates ERROR when output as PDF, please advise how I can fix it？

```
yy = "c:/Program Files/RStudio/www/favicon.ico"

img_uri <- function(x) { sprintf('<img src="%s"/>', knitr::image_uri(x)) }

dat <- data.frame(
  country = c('rstudio'),
  flag = img_uri(yy))
    DT::datatable(dat, escape = FALSE)
```

It works so far to generate a table with image and data altogether. But error pops out when output to pdf.

```
output file: 2019-09-05-EXP-report.knit.md

ERROR: Functions that produce HTML output found in document targeting latex 

output.
Please change the output type of this document to HTML. Alternatively, you can allow
HTML output in non-HTML formats by adding this option to the YAML front-matter of
your rmarkdown file:

  always_allow_html: yes

Note however that the HTML output will not be visible in non-HTML formats.
```

Have add the `always_allow_html: yes` at YAML, but it just stop running. Please advise and many thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can use `datatable` in pdf

Comment: Thanks for advice. Let me try and feed back. Thanks!

Comment: i found the solution from yihui Xie himself. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25106481/add-an-image-to-a-table-like-output-in-r by using `kable()`. Thanks for advice @Matt